# Google Sign-In: backend verification

Tags: node.js, dart, flutter, google-oauth

I have Google Sign-in working on my app: the relevant code is roughly:

```
var acc = await signInService.signIn();
var auth = await acc.authentication;
var token = auth.idToken;
```

This gives me a nice long token, which I then pass to my backend with an HTTP POST (this is working fine), and then try to verify. I have the same google-services.json file in my flutter tree and on the backend server (which is nodejs/restify). The backend code is roughly:

```
let creds = require('./google-services.json');
let auth = require('google-auth-library').OAuth2Client;
let client = new auth(creds.client[0].oauth_client[0].client_id);
. . .
let ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: token,
    audience: creds.client[0].oauth_client[0].client_id
});
let payload = ticket.getPayload();
```

This consistently returns my the error "Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience".

I have also tried registering separately with GCP console and using those keys/client_id instead, but same result. Where can I find the valid client_id that will properly verify this token?

Comment: I have since gotten the code working--the oauth_client array in my google-services.json file has three entries, and it turns out that one of them works. I'd still like to know what is special about that one and why the others don't.

Comment: i'm currently struggling with the same problem. I'm using the same code as you (the second snippet) to verify the id token. You mentioned you have multiple client ids in your json. In my case i only have one. I'm developing a web app where i'm expecting the token from the frontend after logging in with Google Sign-In. Any ideas on what i'm missing ?

Comment: The reason I got it wrong was because I forgot to put .apps.googleusercontent.com after my CLIENT_ID, I just put in the random string part of it in.

Answer (score 17):

The problem here is the `client_id` that is being used to create an OAuth2Client and the `client_id` being used as the `audience` in the `verifyIdToken` is the same. The `client_id` for the `audience` should be the `client_id` that was used in your frontend application to get the `id_token`.

Below is sample code from Google documentation.

```
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
async function verify() {
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: CLIENT_ID,  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
      // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
      //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]
  });
  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  const userid = payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //const domain = payload['hd'];
}
verify().catch(console.error);
```

And here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) for the documentation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used the same `client_id` for both front end and back end, as shown in the documentation, and still get this error.

Comment: Mismatched client ids are definitely not the only cause of this error. As noted below, changing `audience` to `requiredAudience` can fix it, though I have no idea why or if that's even a valid thing to do.

Answer (score 10):

Another quick solution might be change the name of your param "audience" to "requiredAudience". It works to me. If you copied the code from google, maybe the google documentation is outdated.

```
client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken,
      requiredAudience: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
      // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
      //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]
  });
```

Comment: I'll check it out. In my experience, all Google documentation is wrong or outdated. :-)

Comment: I don't find any requiredAudience param.

Comment: this param does not exist in the interface

Comment: Why does this work? This seems kind of dicey.

Answer (score 3):

I've been faceing this issue with google-auth-library version **8.7.0** and came across a workaround only if you have a single CLIENT_ID to verify.
Once you create your **OAuth2Client** like this:

`const googleClient = new OAuth2Client(process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);`

You don't need to pass the **CLIENT_ID** in **verifyIdToken** function as it uses your googleClient object to create auth url.

Comment: this is not true, i tested in 8.8.0 if you not passing CLIENT_ID in verifyIdToken, you are able to get the user information by using mismatch client id in frontend & backend

Comment: @HenryTeh as I mentioned, I've used this for version 8.7.0, it could've been a change in other version. I will surely test it and get back with an update

Answer (score 2):

It has already been mentioned above that `requiredAudience` works instead of `audience`, but I noticed `requiredAudience` works for both `{client_id : <CLIENT_ID>}` and <CLIENT_ID>. So maybe you were referencing `creds.client[0].oauth_client[0]` instead of `creds.client[0].oauth_client[0].client_id`? I have not been able to find any docs on the difference between `requiredAudience` and `audience`, however make sure you are sending just the <CLIENT_ID> instead of `{client_id : <CLIENT_ID>}`.

Google doc: [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

Answer (score 1):

`verifyIdToken()`'s call [signature](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/main/src/auth/oauth2client.ts#L393) doesn't require the `audience` parameter. That's also stated in the [changelog](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#602-2020-06-16). So you can skip it, and it'll work. The documentation is kinda misleading on that.

It's also the reason why using `requiredAudience` works because it actually isn't being used by the method, so it's the same as not providing it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was incorrectly trying to use the "plain", web based client ID of my (firebase) project (this was down as "client_id" in the downloaded, for server purposes json key file),

```
108xxxxxxxx
```

The id of the google cloud project,

```
902xxxxxx
```

But what I was supposed to be using was the client id specifically for the app that was using my OAuth "arm".  In my case, this was for a google script project, and I needed to look in `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials` for my project (OAuth Credentials) and copy the client ID in there,

```
902xxxxxx-abcdefghixxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

The alternative way to find out what it should be in the backend is to drop your JWT token into https://jwt.io (or just decode it yourself).  The correct client ID you should be using is under the "aud" (audience) field.  After I swapped my client ID to that for my OAuth client, everything worked right.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `requiredAudience` is not the correct answer!!!**

I was encountering the same error msg with the people who asked this question

> error: Wrong recipient, payload audience != requiredAudience

I'm using 8.1.0 version for `google-auth-library`, even both of my Front-End & Back-End use same Google Oauth 2.0 Client Id i will still get this error

When i try  changing the `audience` to `requiredAudience` in the `verifyIdToken` function as suggested by @David117Master that **SEEM** able to solve the issue at first. But i was able to get the user account information even when i try to use different `Client Id` in both Front-End & Back-End!!!

> The reason behind of this is explained by @Chuks Jr. answer

So my solution was just to upgrade the npm package to the latest version (8.8.0)

```
npm i google-auth-library
```

Then i use back `audience` key in the `verifyIdToken` function it will always return error if Front-End & Back-End use different `Client Id`

I also found that if no passing in `Client Id` or use `requiredAudience` will result in getting user information even if use the mismatch `Client Id` in Front-End & Back-End

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete audience property:

```
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';

const idToken = "your_front_token";
const clientId = "xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";

const oatuh = new OAuth2Client(clientId);
const googleResponse = await oatuh.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: idToken, 
    // audience: clientId // Delete this property
});
```

At least, it works for me!

**Note**: `^9.2.0` is my `google-auth-library` version